# Adding a Transparent Border Outline to an Overlay Image in Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, graphics, html5-canvas

I am working on a project where I overlay an image on an HTML Canvas and add rounded corners and a shadow to it. However, I'm facing an issue where there is an unwanted white inline border inside the overlay image. How can I add a transparent border outline around the overlay image without this unwanted border? I'm using JavaScript and the Canvas API.
I would also be interested to add the transparent rectangle behind the overlay image so it looks like it outlines the overlay, and I can control the corner radius for the outline separately

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById ('mycanvas');    // access the canvas object
const background = document.getElementById("source");
background.onload = function() {
  const overlay = new Image(300, 300)
  overlay.src = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518826778770-a729fb53327c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1887&q=80';
  overlay.onload = function() {
    var context = canvas.getContext ('2d');                             // access the canvas context
const canvasWidth = background.width; // Set your desired width
const canvasHeight = background.height; // Set your desired height


const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   

// Draw the background image
ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, background.width, background.height); 

const x = (canvas.width - overlay.width) / 2;
    const y = (canvas.height - overlay.height) / 2;

    const cornerRadius = 30;
    const shadowBlur = 93;
    const shadowOffsetX = 0;
    const shadowOffsetY = -116;
    const borderWidth = 30; // Set the width of the border
    const borderColor = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)';

    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(overlay, "no-repeat");

    // Prepare the shadow
    ctx.shadowBlur = shadowBlur;
    ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = shadowOffsetX;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = shadowOffsetY;

    // Place our drawing so that we can see the full shadow
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    // Trace the rounded rectangle (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/roundRect)
    ctx.roundRect(0, 0, overlay.width, overlay.height, cornerRadius);


    ctx.fill();

    // Draw a transparent border outline
    ctx.strokeStyle = borderColor;
    ctx.lineWidth = borderWidth;
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.resetTransform();
    ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
 }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<div style="display:none;">
  <img id="source" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534644107580-3a4dbd494a95?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80" width="500" height="500" />
 
  <img id="overlay" src="" width="300" height="300" />
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is the order of the of your stroke and fill.
here is how it looks if we change the order of those operations:

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

I remove a lot of code from your sample to keep it shorter

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas'); // access the canvas object
const background = document.getElementById("source");
background.onload = function() {
  const overlay = new Image(300, 300)
  overlay.src = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518826778770-a729fb53327c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1887&q=80';
  overlay.onload = function() {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); // access the canvas context
    const canvasWidth = background.width; // Set your desired width
    const canvasHeight = background.height; // Set your desired height
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, background.width, background.height);
    const x = (canvas.width - overlay.width) / 2;
    const y = (canvas.height - overlay.height) / 2;

    const cornerRadius = 30;
    const borderWidth = 30; // Set the width of the border
    const borderColor = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)';

    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(overlay, "no-repeat");

    ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.roundRect(0, 0, overlay.width, overlay.height, cornerRadius);
    ctx.strokeStyle = borderColor;
    ctx.lineWidth = borderWidth;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();

  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<div style="display:none;">
  <img id="source" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534644107580-3a4dbd494a95?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80" width="500" height="500" />
 
  <img id="overlay" src="" width="300" height="300" />
  
</div>
```